# yii 2.0 framework trying to show search results

Tags: php, yii2

I have a submit form with one field called `case_no`, when I enter in the `case_no` it should then populate the table with that specific information that matched the `case_no`.

**Controller:**

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    $model = new LegalCase();

    $category = new Category();

    /*$categories = Category::findAll();*/

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('searchFormSubmitted');




        $case = $model->findByCaseNo($case_no);
        return $this->render('search', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $model->findAll(),
            'results' => $case
        ]);

        return $this->refresh();
    } else {
        return $this->render('search', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
 class LegalCase extends Model
{
public $id;
public $case_no;
public $name;
public $judgement_date;
public $year;
public $neutral_citation;

private static $cases = [
    '100' => [
        'id' => '1',
        'case_no' => '3',
        'name' => 'first case'  
    ],
    '101' => [
        'id' => '1',
        'case_no' => '125',
        'name' => 'second case'
    ],
];

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findAll()
{

    //$query = new Query();
    $provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => self::$cases,
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => ['id', 'case_no', 'name'],
        ],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ],
    ]);

    return $provider->getModels();
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return isset(self::$cases[$id]) ? new static(self::$cases[$id]) : null;
}

/**
 * Finds case by name
 *
 * @param  string      $name
 * @return static|null
 */



/**
 * Finds case by number
 *
 * @param  string      $case_no
 * @return static|null
 */
public static function findByCaseNo($case_no)
{
    foreach (self::$cases as $case) {
        if (strcasecmp($case['case_no'], $case_no) === 0) {
            return new static($case);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**View:**

```
 <?php
 use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\widgets\ListView;

use app\models\LegalCase;

use backend\models\Standard;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model app\models\LegalCase */

$this->title = 'Search';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-login">
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

<p>Please fill out the following fields to login:</p>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'search-form',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-3\">{input}   </div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
        'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label'],
    ],
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'case_no') ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>

<?php /*= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 's_id',
  ArrayHelper::map(Standard::find()->all(), 's_id', 'name'))*/  ?>

<?php


?>





<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'search-button']) ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('searchFormSubmitted')) { ?>

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>case_no</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php //$posts = $results->getModels();
    foreach($results as $case){
        echo '<tr>';
        //print_r($case);
        echo $case;
        //echo $case->id;
        /*echo '<td>' . $post['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $post['case_no'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $post['name'] . '</td>';*/
        echo '</tr>';
    } ?>
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is exactly not working and which errors do you see, if any?

Comment: if i put in the controller $case_no = 3 or $case_no = 125 then it works and picks up the correct case. but if i put Yii::$app->request->post('case_no'); it doesnt

Comment: Print your post array and you will see, that it has the var named LegalCase[case_no], but not case_no.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_POST['LegalCase']['case_no']` instead of `$case_no`.

EDIT: note: I'm using an older version of Yii so things might have changed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
$case = $model->findByCaseNo($model->case_no);
```

But your attribute $case_no will be empty after the form submit. This happened because attribute is not safe. Function load() set only safe model attributes. If you want to load model attributes after submit you need to add validation to the LegalCase model. For example:

```
public function rules()
{
     return [
         ['case_no', 'trim'],
     ];
}
```